# Optimize data model and repository SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to optimize the conception of my data model and repository.
I receive an object that has fields that have to be inserted with different field name.
( Example : A Namespace will not be inserted with his name but with his id that his retrieved from the database findNamespace...)

So actually :

- I have a data model for inserting
- I have a data model for reading
- I have a repository for inserting
- I have a repository for reading method

So my goal is to know if it's "Normal" ? Or if not, what do you purpose to make it better ?

Example :
CheckConfigDeploiementLecture.java //For Reading the data from database

```
@Entity
public class CheckConfigDeploiementLecture extends Content {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Integer id;
    private String namespacename;
    private String servicename;
    private String typeverification;
    private String status;
    private String statuscomplementaire;
    private String details;
    private String actionby;
    private String reportdate;
}
```

CheckConfigDeploiementObjectInsertion.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "checkconfigdeploiement") //to insert the data with namespace id, service id...
public class CheckConfigDeploiementObjectInsertion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message = "IdNamespace ne peut être vide")
    @Column(name = "idnamespace", nullable = false)
    private Integer idnamespace;

    @NotNull(message = "IdServiceNamespace ne peut être vide")
    @Column(name = "idservicenamespace", nullable = false)
    private Integer idservicenamespace;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Typeverification ne peut être NUL")
    @Column(name = "typeverification", nullable = false)
    private String typeverification;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Status ne peut être vide")
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "statuscomplementaire")
    private String statuscomplementaire;

    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;

    @Column(name = "actionby")
    private String actionby;

    @NotEmpty(message = "ReportDate ne peut être vide")
    @Column(name = "reportdate", nullable = false)
    private String reportdate;
```

CheckConfigDeploiementRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CheckConfigDeploiementRepository
        extends CrudRepository<CheckConfigDeploiementObjectInsertion, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT checkconfigdeploiement.id, checkconfigdeploiement.idnamespace, checkconfigdeploiement.idservicenamespace, checkconfigdeploiement.typeverification, checkconfigdeploiement.status, checkconfigdeploiement.statuscomplementaire, checkconfigdeploiement.details, checkconfigdeploiement.actionby, checkconfigdeploiement.reportdate FROM checkconfigdeploiement WHERE checkconfigdeploiement.idnamespace = ?1 and checkconfigdeploiement.idservicenamespace = ?2 and checkconfigdeploiement.typeverification = ?3", nativeQuery = true)
    CheckConfigDeploiementObjectInsertion findBynamespacenameandservicenameandtypeverification(Integer idnamespacename,
            Integer idservicename, String typeverification);
}
```

CheckConfigDeploiementRepositoryLecture.java

```
@Repository
public interface CheckConfigDeploiementRepositoryLecture
        extends CrudRepository<CheckConfigDeploiementLecture, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT checkconfigdeploiement.id, categorienamespaces.namespacename, servicesnamespaces.servicename, typeverification, status, statuscomplementaire, details, actionby, reportdate FROM categorienamespaces, servicesnamespaces, checkconfigdeploiement WHERE categorienamespaces.id = checkconfigdeploiement.idnamespace and servicesnamespaces.id = checkconfigdeploiement.idservicenamespace", nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<CheckConfigDeploiementLecture> findAll();
}
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data allows you to use interfaces called "projections" when querying your database. That would be the best way to retrieve only the fields you are interested in.

I wouldn't use two @Entity class and two repositories for the same database table, and I don't think I've ever seen any project using this approach, so I guess you could say it's not "normal" ;)

See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Comment: I checked the documentation but i don't see any information that can help.
I don't thing "projections" is what i need.
My Front send a object of a specific type and i need to save it with different fields. And when i want to read from database, i need to read it as it has been inserted.

Comment: If the objects you want to save in your database is different from the objects you use in your front-end application, you might need "Data Transfer Objects" (DTO). Theses objects only contain the data that you need to transfer from your front-end to your back-end, or the other way around.